# In PWA, Add to Homescreen Popoup show everytime when website is open

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, progressive-web-apps

I have added PWA in my previously created asp.net MVC web application. Now I want that **Add to homescreen Popup** open every time when application open. I have attached my code for adding pwa in Website.

1) code of my AdminLayout.cshtml

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - PULSE</title>
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <meta name="description" content="PMS System">
    <meta name="author" content="Ashish Durve">


    @{ Html.RenderPartial("GoogleAnalytics"); }
    <!-- Add to home screen for Safari on iOS -->
    @*<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="Pulse">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/icons/icon-152x152.png">*@


    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")



    <link href="../Content/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href="../Content/vendors/easypiechart/jquery.easy-pie-chart.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">

    <link href="~/Content/assets/login_home.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    @*Old Fontawsome 4.4.0 reference for old icons which are not included in new fontawsome 5.0.10*@
    <link href="../../Content/bootstrap/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    @* New fontawsome 5.0.10 reference*@
    <link href="../../Content/assets/fontawesome-all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <link rel="manifest" href="~/manifest.json"> @*code for pwa manifest*@


    <!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <script src="../Content/vendors/modernizr-2.6.2-respond-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../Content/vendors/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>


    <script src="../../Content/bootstrap/js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../Content/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../Content/assets/bootstrap-material-design.js"></script>



    <!--/.fluid-container-->
    @*<script src="../../Content/vendors/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../../Content/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>*@
    <script src="../../Content/vendors/easypiechart/jquery.easy-pie-chart.js"></script>
    <script src="../../Content/assets/scripts.js"></script>
    <script src="../../Content/vendors/bootstrap-wysihtml5/lib/js/wysihtml5-0.3.0.js"></script>
    <script src="../../Content/assets/rhinoslider-1.05.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../Content/assets/mousewheel.js"></script>
    <script src="../../Content/assets/easing.js"></script>

    <!-- Material Design fonts -->
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700" type="text/css">-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Bootstrap Material Design -->
    <link href="../../Content/assets/bootstrap-material-design.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../../Content/assets/ripples.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    @*<link href="../../Content/assets/addtohomescreen.css" rel="stylesheet" />

        <script src="../../Content/assets/addtohomescreen.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../../Content/assets/addtohomescreen.js"></script>*@

    <script src="../../Content/assets/material.js"></script>
    @*<script src="../../Content/assets/bootstrap-material-design.js"></script>*@
    <script src="../../Content/assets/ripples.min.js"></script>

    <!--iphone PWA AppIcon Reference -->
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="touch-icon-iphone.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="touch-icon-ipad.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="touch-icon-iphone-retina.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="167x167" href="touch-icon-ipad-retina.png">



    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="/apple-icon-57x57.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="/apple-icon-60x60.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="/apple-icon-72x72.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="/apple-icon-76x76.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="/apple-icon-114x114.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="/apple-icon-120x120.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="/apple-icon-144x144.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="/apple-icon-152x152.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-icon-180x180.png">
    <!--End-->
    <!--iphone PWA Splash Screen Reference -->

    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">



    <link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="/launch.png">


    <!-- iPhone X (1125px x 2436px) -->
    <link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="(device-width: 375px) and (device-height: 812px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3)" href="/apple-launch-1125x2436.png">
    <!-- iPhone 8, 7, 6s, 6 (750px x 1334px) -->
    <link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="(device-width: 375px) and (device-height: 667px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" href="/apple-launch-750x1334.png">
    <!-- iPhone 8 Plus, 7 Plus, 6s Plus, 6 Plus (1242px x 2208px) -->
    <link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="(device-width: 414px) and (device-height: 736px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3)" href="/apple-launch-1242x2208.png">
    <!-- iPhone 5 (640px x 1136px) -->
    <link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="(device-width: 320px) and (device-height: 568px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" href="/apple-launch-640x1136.png">
    <!-- iPad Mini, Air (1536px x 2048px) -->
    <link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="(device-width: 768px) and (device-height: 1024px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" href="/apple-launch-1536x2048.png">
    <!-- iPad Pro 10.5" (1668px x 2224px) -->
    <link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="(device-width: 834px) and (device-height: 1112px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" href="/apple-launch-1668x2224.png">
    <!-- iPad Pro 12.9" (2048px x 2732px) -->
    <link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="(device-width: 1024px) and (device-height: 1366px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" href="/apple-launch-2048x2732.png">


    <!--End-->



    <script>
        $.material.init();
    </script>

    @*<script>
            $(document).ready(function () { $('body').bootstrapMaterialDesign(); });
        </script>*@

    <style>
        @@media all and (display-mode: standalone) {
            body {
                background-color: yellow;
            }
        }
    </style>

</head>
    <body class="pattern">
        
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row-fluid">

               
                <!--/span-->
                @RenderBody()

            </div>
            
            <footer>
              
            </footer>
        </div>
     

       
       <script type="text/javascript">

           var err = 0;
           var handleError;
           $(document).ready(function () {
              //add to home screen code
               window.addEventListener("beforeinstallprompt", function (e) {
                   // log the platforms provided as options in an install prompt 
                   //console.log(e.platforms); // e.g., ["web", "android", "windows"] 
                   e.userChoice.then(function (outcome) {
                       //console.log(outcome); // either "accepted" or "dismissed"
                   }, handleError);
               });

               //window.addEventListener('appinstalled', (evt) => {
               //    app.logEvent('a2hs', 'installed');
               //});
               /////////////////////////////////
           //    //uncomment the below code
           //    let deferredPrompt;

               window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', (e) => {
                   // Prevent Chrome 67 and earlier from automatically showing the prompt
                   e.preventDefault();
                                  
                   // Stash the event so it can be triggered later.
                   deferredPrompt = e;

                   deferredPrompt.prompt();


                   deferredPrompt.userChoice
                       .then((choiceResult) => {
                           if (choiceResult.outcome === 'accepted') {
                               //console.log('User accepted the A2HS prompt');
                           } else {
                               //console.log('User dismissed the A2HS prompt');
                           }
                           deferredPrompt = null;
                       });
               });
               window.addEventListener('appinstalled', (evt) => {
                   app.logEvent('a2hs', 'installed');
               });
           ////    notify the user your app can be installed
           //    window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', (e) => {
           //        e.preventDefault();
           //        deferredPrompt = e;
           //        // Update UI notify the user they can add to home screen
           //        btnAdd.style.display = 'block';
           //    });

               //////Show prompt

               //btnAdd.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
               //    // hide our user interface that shows our A2HS button
               //    btnAdd.style.display = 'none';
               //    // Show the prompt
               //    deferredPrompt.prompt();
               //    // Wait for the user to respond to the prompt
               //    deferredPrompt.userChoice
               //        .then((choiceResult) => {
               //            if (choiceResult.outcome === 'accepted') {
               //                console.log('User accepted the A2HS prompt');
               //            } else {
               //                console.log('User dismissed the A2HS prompt');
               //            }
               //            deferredPrompt = null;
               //        });
               //});

                $('#slider').rhinoslider({
                    controlsPlayPause: false,
                    showControls: 'always',
                    showBullets: 'always',
                    controlsMousewheel: false,
                    prevText: 'Back',
                    nextText:'Proceed',
      slidePrevDirection: 'toRight',
      slideNextDirection: 'toLeft',
      cycled: 'false',
                    controlsKeyboard: 'false'
                });


                $(".rhino-prev").hide();
                $('.rhino-next').after('<a class="form-submit" href="javascript:void(0);" >Proceed</a>');
                $(".rhino-next").hide();




                var info = ["PERSONAL DETAILS","ACCOUNT DETAILS","ORGANIZATION DETAILS"];
                var images = ["../../Content/Images/personal-details-icon.png", "../../Content/Images/account-details.png", "../../Content/Images/contact-details.png"];
                $('.rhino-bullet').each(function(index){
                    $(this).html('<p style="margin: 0pt; font-size: 13px; font-weight: bold;"><img src="./img/'+
                        images[index]+'"></p><p class="bullet-desc">'+info[index]+'</p></a>');
                });





            });

            $('body').on('click', '.form-submit', function(){
//            $('.form-submit').on("click",function(){                

                $('.form-error').html("");
                err = 0;
                var current_tab = $('#slider').find('.rhino-active').attr("id");

                switch(current_tab){
                    case 'rhino-item0':
                        step1_validation();
                        break;
                    case 'rhino-item1':
                        step2_validation();
                        break;
                    case 'rhino-item2':
                        step3_validation();
                        if (err == 0) {
                            //alert(err);
                            $("#freeRegister").submit();
                        }
                        break;
                }
            });

            var step1_validation = function(){

                //var err = 0;

                if($('#fname').val() == ''){
                    $('#fname').parent().find('.form-error').html("Please enter first name.");
                    err++;
                }
                if($('#lname').val() == ''){
                    $('#lname').parent().find('.form-error').html("Please enter last name.");
                    err++;
                }
                if ($('#mobile').val() == '') {
                    $('#mobile').parent().find('.form-error').html("Please enter mobile phone number.");
                    err++;
                }
                else {
                    var x = $('#mobile').val();
                    var phoneno = /^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/;
                    if (!x.match(phoneno)) {
                        $('#mobile').parent().find('.form-error').html("Please enter valid mobile phone number.");
                        err++;
                    }
                }

                
                if(err == 0){
                    $(".rhino-active-bullet").removeClass("step-error").addClass("step-success");
                    $(".rhino-next").show();
                    $('.form-submit').hide();
                    $('.rhino-next').trigger('click');
                }else{
                    $(".rhino-active-bullet").removeClass("step-success").addClass("step-error");
                }


            };

            var step2_validation = function(){
                //var err = 0;

                if ($('#username').val() == '') {
                    $('#username').parent().find('.form-error').html("Please enter UserName/Email.");
                    err++;
                }
                else {
                    var x = $('#username').val();
                    var userName =  /^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i;

                    if (!x.match(userName)) {
                        $('#username').parent().find('.form-error').html("Please enter valid Email.");
                        err++;
                    }                    
                    if (!checkUserName(x)) {
                        $('#username').parent().find('.form-error').html("This user is already registered with us.");
                        err++;
                    }
                }

                if($('#pass').val() == ''){
                    $('#pass').parent().find('.form-error').html("Please enter password");
                    err++;
                }
                if ($('#cpass').val() == '') {
                    $('#cpass').parent().find('.form-error').html("Please enter confirm password.");
                    err++;
                }
                else {
                    var pass = $('#pass').val();
                    var cpass = $('#cpass').val();

                    if (pass != cpass) {
                        $('#cpass').parent().find('.form-error').html("Confirm password should match password field.");
                        err++;
                    }
                }
                
                if(err == 0){
                    $(".rhino-active-bullet").removeClass("step-error").addClass("step-success");
                    $(".rhino-next").show();
                    $('.form-submit').hide();
                    $('.rhino-next').trigger('click');
                }else{
                    $(".rhino-active-bullet").removeClass("step-success").addClass("step-error");
                }

            };

            var step3_validation = function(){
                //var err = 0;

                if($('#orgName').val() == ''){
                    $('#orgName').parent().find('.form-error').html("Please enter organization name.");
                    err++;
                }
                if(err == 0){
                    $(".rhino-active-bullet").removeClass("step-error").addClass("step-success");
                    $(".rhino-next").show();
                    $('.form-submit').hide();
                    $('.rhino-next').trigger('click');
                }else{
                    $(".rhino-active-bullet").removeClass("step-success").addClass("step-error");
                }

            };

            function checkUserName(userName) {
                valid = false;
                url = "../Account/VerifyUserName?userName=" + userName;
                $.ajax(
                {
                    url: url,
                    type: "GET",
                    async: false,
                    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {                        
                        if (data == "0") {
                            
                            valid = false;
                        }
                        else {                            
                            valid = true;
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                       
                        alert("Failed to get data. Please contact support team.")
                        return false;
                    }
                });
                
                return valid;
           }

        </script>
                        
        @*<div class="overlay"></div>*@
  </body>
</html>
      

<script>
    // code for service worker of pwa start
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        console.log("Will the service worker register?");
     
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('../serviceWorker.js')
            .then(function (reg) {
                console.log(reg);
                console.log("Yes, it did.");
            }).catch(function (err) {
                console.log("No it didn't. This happened: ", err)
            });
    }
    // code for service worker of pwa end
</script>  


<script>
   

    var deferredPrompt;

    window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', function (e) {
        // Prevent Chrome 67 and earlier from automatically showing the prompt
        e.preventDefault();
        // Stash the event so it can be triggered later.
        deferredPrompt = e;

        showAddToHomeScreen();

    });

</script>
```

2) serviseworker.js

```js
(function () {
    'use strict';
   
   
    var version = 'v1.0::CacheFirstSafe';
    var offlineUrl = "../Controller/Account/Login.cshtml"; // <-- Offline/Index.cshtml
    var urlsToCache = ['/', offlineUrl]; // <-- Add more URLs you would like to cache.

    // Store core files in a cache (including a page to display when offline)
    function updateStaticCache() {
        return caches.open(version)
            .then(function (cache) {
                return cache.addAll(urlsToCache);
            });
    }

    function addToCache(request, response) {
        if (!response.ok && response.type !== 'opaque')
            return;

        var copy = response.clone();
        caches.open(version)

            .then(function (cache) {
                cache.put(request, copy);
            });
    }

    function serveOfflineImage(request) {
        if (request.headers.get('Accept').indexOf('image') !== -1) {
            return new Response('<svg role="img" aria-labelledby="offline-title" viewBox="0 0 400 300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><title id="offline-title">Offline</title><g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd"><path fill="#D8D8D8" d="M0 0h400v300H0z"/><text fill="#9B9B9B" font-family="Helvetica Neue,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif" font-size="72" font-weight="bold"><tspan x="93" y="172">offline</tspan></text></g></svg>', { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'image/svg+xml' } });
        }
    }

    self.addEventListener('install', function (event) {
        event.waitUntil(updateStaticCache());
    });

    self.addEventListener('activate', function (event) {
        event.waitUntil(
            caches.keys()
                .then(function (keys) {
                    // Remove caches whose name is no longer valid
                    return Promise.all(keys
                        .filter(function (key) {
                            return key.indexOf(version) !== 0;
                        })
                        .map(function (key) {
                            return caches.delete(key);
                        })
                    );
                })
        );
    });

    self.addEventListener('fetch', function (event) {
        var request = event.request;

        // Always fetch non-GET requests from the network
        if (request.method !== 'GET' || request.url.match('../Controller/Account/Login.cshtml')) {
            event.respondWith(
                fetch(request)
                    .catch(function () {
                        return caches.match(offlineUrl);
                    })
            );
            return;
        }

        // For HTML requests, try the network first, fall back to the cache, finally the offline page
        if (request.headers.get('Accept').indexOf('text/html') !== -1) {
            event.respondWith(
                fetch(request)
                    .then(function (response) {
                        // Stash a copy of this page in the cache
                        addToCache(request, response);
                        return response;
                    })
                    .catch(function () {
                        return caches.match(request)
                            .then(function (response) {
                                return response || caches.match(offlineUrl);
                            });
                    })
            );
            return;
        }

        // cache first for fingerprinted resources
        if (request.url.match(/(\?|&)v=/ig)) {
            event.respondWith(
                caches.match(request)
                    .then(function (response) {
                        return response || fetch(request)
                            .then(function (response) {
                                addToCache(request, response);
                                return response || serveOfflineImage(request);
                            })
                            .catch(function () {
                                return serveOfflineImage(request);
                            });
                    })
            );

            return;
        }

        // network first for non-fingerprinted resources
        event.respondWith(
            fetch(request)
                .then(function (response) {
                    // Stash a copy of this page in the cache
                    addToCache(request, response);
                    return response;
                })
                .catch(function () {
                    return caches.match(request)
                        .then(function (response) {
                            return response || serveOfflineImage(request);
                        })
                        .catch(function () {
                            return serveOfflineImage(request);
                        });
                })
        );
    });
})();
```

4) Manifest.json

{
  "name": "Pulse",
  "short_name": "Pulse",
  "description": "Pulse Progressive Web Application",
  "icons": [

```
{
  "src": "../../Content/images/icon16x16.png",
  "sizes": "16x16",
  "type": "image/png",
  "density": 0.25
},
{
  "src": "../../Content/images/icon20x20.png",
  "sizes": "20x20",
  "type": "image/png",
  "density": 0.5
},
{
  "src": "../../Content/images/icon32x32.png",
  "sizes": "32x32",
  "type": "image/png"

},
{
  "src": "../../Content/images/icon36x36.png",
  "sizes": "36x36",
  "type": "image/png",
  "density": 0.75
},
{
  "src": "../../Content/images/icon40x40.png",
  "sizes": "40x40",
  "type": "image/png"

},
{
  "src": "../../Content/images/icon48x48.png",
  "sizes": "48x48",
  "type": "image/png",
  "density": 1.0
},

{
  "src": "../../Content/images/icon60x60.png",
  "sizes": "60x60",
  "type": "image/png"

},
{
  "src": "../../Content/images/icon64x64.png",
  "sizes": "64x64",
  "type": "image/png"

},



{
  "src": "../../Content/images/icon72x72.png",
  "sizes": "72x72",
  "type": "image/png",
  "density": 1.5
},

{
  "src": "../../Content/images/icon88x88.png",
  "sizes": "88x88",
  "type": "image/png"
},



{
  "src": "../../Content/images/icon96x96.png",
  "sizes": "96x96",
  "type": "image/png",
  "density": 2.0
},

{
  "src": "../../Content/images/icon128x128.png",
  "sizes": "128x128",
  "type": "image/png",
  "density": 2.0
},

{
  "src": "../../Content/images/icon144x144.png",
  "sizes": "144x144",
  "type": "image/png",
  "density": 3.0
},

{
  "src": "../../Content/images/icon172x172.png",
  "sizes": "172x172",
  "type": "image/png"

},


{
  "src": "../../Content/images/icon192x192.png",
  "sizes": "192x192",
  "type": "image/png",
  "density": 4.0
},


{
  "src": "../../Content/images/icon196x196.png",
  "sizes": "196x196",
  "type": "image/png"

},

{
  "src": "../../Content/images/icon256x256.png",
  "sizes": "256x256",
  "type": "image/png"

},

{
  "src": "../../Content/images/icon512x512.png",
  "sizes": "512x512",
  "type": "image/png",
  "density": 5.0
},

{
  "src": "../../Content/images/icon1024x1024.png",
  "sizes": "1024x1024",
  "type": "image/png"

}
```

],
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#536878",
  "background_color": "#fff",

"start_url": "/"
}

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/55159512/edit) the question to be on-topic: include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that duplicates the problem. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: When you run the Chrome Lighthouse audit, do you see any errors or suggestions for improvement? There are usually things there to help you.

Comment: Hello @Mathias, When My page is loading I am getting this error in console: **Uncaught (in promise) DOMException** . Please help me.

Comment: Have you run the chrome lighthouse tools and looked at the messages there? Google the error messages seen there (if any). Lighthouse is the best tool to use.

Comment: Hello @Mathias this problem is solved but now I have Problem that I need **Add to homescreen Popup** every time shown when site is open. please Help me In that.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand what the problem is. You can only add to home screen once.

Comment: Hi, @Mathias . I need **Add to homescreen Popup** when my site is open in mobile , desktop.

Comment: You can only do A2HS once. While testing, you need to clear your browser cache and uninstall the app (Chrome) EACH time after you install to test again.